# Google Earth popup video (ActiveX)

Tags: video, activex, google-earth

Is it possible to place an ActiveX control in a Google Earth placemark pop up?

I have a proprietary third party activex control that I can put in embed in HTML. Would this work for Google Earth?

Answer (score 1):

You should try and place the html mark-up for your activex control into a simple Kml file to test it out.

Save the code example as 'test.kml' and inset your embedding code at the point indicated. Then just open the 'test.kml' file in Google Earth. The control should be inside the 'simple activex test' place-mark balloon.

I know that embedding flash in this way works - but without knowing what the control is you are using it is hard to say if it will or not for you in this case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <Placemark>
      <name>simple activex test</name>
      <description>
        <![CDATA[
          <!-- code to embed activex control code here -->
        ]]>
      </description>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>52,-1</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```